# drive directories in /dev after dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot

After installing 19.04 in dual boot on a Windows 10 laptop, I have

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p4
```

I haven't seen this before.

I've been using Linux since 1994 and have always seen drives as

```
/dev/sd<a><n>
```

I do have a `/dev/sda1` but that's a USB drive. The install process at first wanted to install to that USB drive.

Is this a new thing or is this Asus a strange device? I haven't installed a dual boot in a long time. I usually install completely and I run a number of VMs so this could be normal for dual boot.

Comment: That tells you that the disk is a NVME flash drive and not an old fashioned scsi/sas drive.

Comment: You have a NVME type SSD and that's how they're named is Linux since the beginning. Normal and unrelated to the laptop's brand.

Comment: And the SSD is attached through PCIe. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive/NVMe